# In MSHTML, what do the numbers mean? Like in IHTMLElement7?

Tags: mshtml

In MSHTML the interfaces are often numbered.  The numbers are at the end of the interface names like `IHTML{name}{number}`. Interfaces like:

- `IHTMLRuleStyle`
- `IHTMLRuleStyle2`
- ...
- `IHTMLRuleStyle6`

or

- `IHTMLElement`
- `IHTMLElement2`
- ...
- `IHTMLElement7`

A list can be seen in [this Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: They're extension interfaces for the base interface. They provide additional features. The higher the number, the higher MSHTML version needed, which may also require higher Internet Explorer version.

Comment: @Jay From your description it sounds like there is no direct relation of those numbers to any IE version, CSS spec version, HTML spec version, etc... It simply means the MSHTML version? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I meant the DLL version, software version. Not the web standard version.

Comment: @Jay Thanks. You want to post an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Jay for your comments.

The numbers represent the version of MSHTML and the version numbers have an indirect relationship with the version of Internet Explorer, CSS, HTML, etc...

I wish I had did this search before but [Geoff Chappell's site](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/ie/mshtml/history/index.htm) has a great chart mapping versions of MSHTML to IE and Windows.

```
Versions of things
MSHTML  IE      Windows
6.0     6.0     Windows XP
6.0     6.0     Windows Server 2003
7.0     7.0     Windows Vista
8.0     8.0     Windows 7
```

Judging from the chart, the version of MSHTML is closely related to the version of Internet Explorer.