# 7 IHTMLElements - What is their difference?

Tags: internet-explorer, watin, mshtml

I was trying to extend WatiN functionality and came across these terms - so could anyone please explain what is the difference between `IHTMLElement`, `IHTMLElement2`, `IHTMLElement3`, `IHTMLElement4`, `IHTMLElement5`, `IHTMLElement6` and `IHTMLElement7`?

What should be used when?
I see same methods / properties available in some of these objects.
I was trying to use the `removeAttribute`, `hasAttribute` and `getBoundingClientRect` methods.

Comment: This has been already addressed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016084/in-mshtml-what-do-the-numbers-mean-like-in-ihtmlelement7